# How to autoplay play unmuted media without user interaction on angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Can it be done? I've been tryind to find some workarounds for a couple of hours now, like triggering a click event on an undisplayed button after the page loaded or using ngAfterViewChecked, I need to do this because I'm trying to create a game and I want the main menu to have some background music, obviously I'll add the options to mute it and turn up/down the volume later, but I'd really like it to start with it instead of having something that says "ehy click me to turn on the music" coz that would be quite stupid and ugly on the page, what's odd is that like 80% of the times when I re-compile the music starts, but when I reload the page not

Comment: what are you using to play music? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio?

Comment: an HTMLAudioElement from ts

Comment: Have you tried playing the audio from other lifecyclehooks?
https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks

Comment: The requirement of "user interaction" is unavoidable, but some environments (e.g. [Puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer)) allow you to set [``event.isTrusted``](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) to `true`, which I currently understand to be the criterion for "user interaction" in events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most browsers today require user interaction unfortunately, no way around it. The button could just say "click to start"

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide

Comment: Yep, noticed. I had to open a modal on load that asks the user to insert the name he'd like to be identified as, or login/sign up. The music starts when the modal is closed and since the user can't avoid interacting with it it's free real estate lmao